# Accessing the vocabulary used by the vectorizer of the best estimator in GridSearch

Tags: scikit-learn, grid-search, countvectorizer

Didn't know to put it best in the title.

This is what I am trying to do: I am using `GridSearch` with a `pipeline` to train classifiers. I would like to see the `vocabulary_.items()` of the `CountVectorizer` used by the best estimator.

Right now, I am doing this, after running `GridSearch`:

```
classifier = gs_clf.best_estimator_
    vect = classifier.named_steps["vec"]
    data = vect.fit_transform(x_train)
    vocab = = vect.vocabulary_.items()
```

Is there any way to get the vocabulary items directly, without using `fit_transform` again on the `CountVectorizer`?

Comment: Is your grid search over parameters of the Vectorizer, or just parameters of the classifier?

Comment: It is over parameters for both. And for the vectorizer, the parameters are min_dif, n_gram_range, analyzer and lowercase.

Comment: Sorry, if that's the case, I'm unaware of a way to persist the vocabulary.